# Test with array and mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Here is my function I want to test:

```
template<typename T>
void free_items(std::vector<T*>& items)
{
    std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), [](T* (&item)){delete item; item = nullptr; });
}
```

I expect the each pointer in my result vector will be freed and be set null correctly. So I write down the following test code.

This is my mock class:

```
struct FreeItemMock
{
    FreeItemMock(bool& destroyed):m_destroyed (destroyed) {}
    ~FreeItemMock(){ m_destroyed = true;}
    bool& m_destroyed ;
};
```

Here is my test code:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_free_items)
{
    bool destroyed[3] = {};
    std::vector<FreeItemMock*> mocks;

    mocks.push_back(new FreeItemMock(destroyed[0]));
    mocks.push_back(new FreeItemMock(destroyed[1]));
    mocks.push_back(new FreeItemMock(destroyed[2]));

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(destroyed[0], false);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(destroyed[1], false);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(destroyed[2], false);

    free_items(mocks);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(destroyed[0], true);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(destroyed[1], true);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(destroyed[2], true);

    BOOST_CHECK(mocks[0] == nullptr);
    BOOST_CHECK(mocks[1] == nullptr);
    BOOST_CHECK(mocks[2] == nullptr);
}
```

The following are my questions:

1. Is the my so-called `FreeItemMock` a mock or a stub? I am not sure whether I pick the right name on my testee-class. According to the book *The art of unit testing with examples in C#*. A mock is used to test whether the interaction with other classed happened. I use my `FreeItemMock` to test its destructor is called, but after invoke the free_item my `FreeItemMock` actually does not exist anymore. It looks the `destroyed[3]` array variable is more like a `mock`.
2. The function I want to test is doing job on a vector, so I need to prepare a array of data to test. Is it correct to hand write a serious of fixture like `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]` and `assert` the result? Because the books also says a unit test should not have "logic" (like `while`, `for`-loop, `if`) to increase its complexity.

   Or should I make a testing utility to help me produce the array data, and make another test for the utility?
3. Is it necessary to check the pre-test value of destroyed? Is it clearer to tell the reader that this function would make destroyed from 0 to 1? Or It is just too tedious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you accept definition Fowler uses you should name them "stubs":

> **Stubs** provide canned answers to calls made during the test, usually not responding at all to anything outside what's programmed in
>   for the test. Stubs may also record information. ([Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) )

Given the structure of the code if you want to cover with a suite of test should at least test how it works under a large set of input:

- Empty array
- Single element array
- Array filled with null element
- Array with a arbitrary number of element

with a different test for each of this cases

For this reason I suppose you should write a function that "allocate" an array, to avoid code repetition in the test (also tests must have code that you can maintain!). So I think yes you should put all the logic that can help you inside the test.

I'm not a fan of test not that test themselves, but in this case all the test make sense only if you invoke `FreeItemMock` with a reference to a bool, so yes I think make sense to test it, but I suggest you put it destructor, before changing the value, in this you are sure that you transaction from `false` to `true` is a really transaction and not a `false` to `false`

Comment: 1. What is a # of element?
2. Should I separate 4 test cases according to different array items? Because the book also says one concern in one test.

Comment: I've extended the question to explain better this two points. Thank you for you comment!